# Select2 Ajax and more data for option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to append more data-* to option tag when it selected by users.
This is my code.Option append only with value and data-select2-id attributes , after being displayed and selected. But i need more data attributes.

```
$('.itemName').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an item',
        ajax: {
            url: '/autocompleteSearch',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function (data,params) {
                console.log(data);
                return {
                    results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.id,
                            text: item.title,
                            otherfield: item.slug

                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
```

Note that otherfield not appended to option .

Comment: Hi Farid, how are you trying to get the `otherfield`?

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk  i don't know how i can use otherfield